# Remove the notification icon from the status bar

Tags: android

I am displaying an icon in status bar.Now I want to remove that icon immediately when I open that content, after some time if we receive any alert, that icon will be displayed again. How can I do this?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Use the NotificationManager to cancel your notification. You only need to provide your notification id.

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/NotificationManager.html

```
private static final int MY_NOTIFICATION_ID= 1234;
String ns = Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE;
NotificationManager mNotificationManager;
mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(ns);
mNotificationManager.notify(MY_NOTIFICATION_ID, notification);
```

The example code is not complete. It depends on how your created your notification.
Just make sure you use the same id to cancel your notification as you used when you created your notification.

To cancel:

```
mNotificationManager.cancel(MY_NOTIFICATION_ID);
```

Answer (score 15):

If you want to remove the notification once user clicked on it, set notification flag [FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Notification.html#FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL) before you create the notification.

Answer (score 1):

I used the Builder patter so you can just set auto cancel from the setter `setAutoCancel(true)`.  That looks something like this:

```
    String title = "Requests"; 
    String msg = "New requests available.";
    NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder =
            new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_gcm_icon)
                    .setContentTitle(title)
                    .setAutoCancel(true)
                    .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle()
                            .bigText(msg))
                    .setContentText(msg);

    mBuilder.setContentIntent(contentIntent);
    mNotificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, mBuilder.build());
```

Answer (score -1):

```
Intent resultIntent = new Intent(application, MainActivity.class);
resultIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
PendingIntent resultPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(application, 0, resultIntent, 0);
NotificationManager nmgr = (NotificationManager) application.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(application)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.icon_battery)
            .setContentTitle(application.getString(R.string.app_name))
            .setContentText("your text")
            .setOnlyAlertOnce(false)
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .setTicker("your ticker")
            .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND  ) //| Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE
            .setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent)
            .setVisibility(VISIBILITY_SECRET)
            .setPriority(Notification.PRIORITY_MIN);

Notification mNotification = mBuilder.build();
//  mNotification.flags |= FLAG_NO_CLEAR;
nmgr.notify(0, mNotification);
```