# Remove Notification in android

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

i am developing one application in that i have successfully receive notification but i unable to remove notification i wrote some code it is not working please tell me where i made mistake

my code

**GcmIntentService**

```
private void sendNotification(long when, String msg) {
    mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager)
    this.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);


    Intent myintent = new Intent(this, ReceiveActivity.class);
    myintent.putExtra("message", msg);
    myintent.setData(Uri.parse("content://" + when));
    PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0,
        myintent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_stat_gcm)
        .setContentTitle("Event tracker")
        .setContentText("Events received");
    Notification notification = mBuilder.build();
    /* NotificationCompat.InboxStyle inboxStyle =
            new NotificationCompat.InboxStyle();


    String[] events = new String[6];
    // Sets a title for the Inbox style big view
    inboxStyle.setBigContentTitle("Event tracker details:");

    // Moves events into the big view
    for (int i=0; i < events.length; i++) {

        inboxStyle.addLine(events[i]);
    }
    // Moves the big view style object into the notification object.
    mBuilder.setStyle(inboxStyle);
*/

    AudioManager am = (AudioManager) this.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);

    /* Even if the mode is set to "Sound & Vibration" in the phone, 
     * the status code that getRingerMode() returns is RINGER_MODE_NORMAL.
     */
    switch (am.getRingerMode()) {
    case AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_VIBRATE:
        mBuilder.setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE);
        break;
    case AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_NORMAL:
        mBuilder.setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND);
        break;
    default:
        mBuilder.setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND);
    }




    mBuilder.setContentIntent(contentIntent);
    mNotificationManager.notify((int) when, mBuilder.build());



}
public void CancelNotification(Context ctx, int notId) {
    String ns = Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE;
    NotificationManager nMgr = (NotificationManager) ctx
        .getSystemService(ns);
    nMgr.cancel(notId);

}
}
```

**in receive activity**

```
TextView name;
TextView deal;
TextView valid;
TextView address;
JSONObject json;
GcmIntentService serv;
Context mContext;

@Override   
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_receive);
    Intent intent = getIntent();


    name = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.name);
    deal = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.deal);
    valid = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.valid);
    address = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.address);
    String message = intent.getExtras().getString("message");
    try {
        json = new JSONObject(message);
        String stime = json.getString("name");
        name.setText(stime);

        String slecturename = json.getString("deal");
        deal.setText(slecturename);

        String sroom = json.getString("valid");
        valid.setText(sroom);

        String sfaculty = json.getString("address");
        address.setText(sfaculty);


    } catch (JSONException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


}

@
Override
protected void onResume() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onResume();
    serv = new GcmIntentService();
    serv.CancelNotification(getApplicationContext(), (int) Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis());
}
}
```

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3595232/android-remove-notification-from-notification-bar

Comment: `it is not working` ????

Comment: ya i called same method from receiveactivity it shows error

Comment: so post logcat error and relative code

Comment: Whatever else is wrong, the notification id that you use for the cancellation is based on a current time. It won't be the one you generated it with

Answer (score 2):

```
serv.CancelNotification(getApplicationContext(), (int) Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis());

mNotificationManager.notify((int) when, mBuilder.build());
```

I am sure in above case `(int) when != (int) Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis()`

You should use same Ids for showing and cancelling the notification.

Below is the reference link.

[http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/NotificationManager.html#cancel(java.lang.String, int)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/NotificationManager.html#cancel%28java.lang.String,%20int%29)

Comment: i wrote in two separate classes  public void CancelNotification(Context ctx) {
        String ns = Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE;
        NotificationManager nMgr = (NotificationManager) ctx
                .getSystemService(ns);
        nMgr.cancel((int) Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis());
       
    }

Comment: in on receive activity under onResume() serv=new GcmIntentService();
 serv.CancelNotification(getApplicationContext());

Comment: @Durga Create Constant int Id field and use same id in both the places.

Comment: how i can pass same id from intentservice class to activity

Comment: Create a New Helper class Utils.java and declare public static final int id variable there.Then you can access it in any class like Utils.id

Comment: ya its working but i have been receiving multiple notificatons but if i use this method it removes privoius notification,only shows one notification

Comment: i want remove only when i open notification,i hope u understand my problem

Answer (score 0):

Dude here  `serv.CancelNotification(getApplicationContext(), (int) Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis());`

this :  `(int) Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis()` should be equal to the Notification ID that you want to cancel or here you send current time in millis which is believe is not the notification id that started the notification you want to close

Try this 
to start the notification use this : `mNotificationManager.notify((int) when, mBuilder.build());` ok

but fine a way to save this when for this notif as its ID

then to cancel it just use the previous saved when to retrieve the notif
`serv.CancelNotification(getApplicationContext(), (int) when);`