# how to delete a android notification?

Tags: java, android, notifications

I want to push a notification to the user every X minutes.

However if there already exist an unread notification,

I want to delete it and replace it with a new one. How can I delete?

How can I check how many unread notification my app has already pushed?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android: remove notification from notification bar](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3595232/android-remove-notification-from-notification-bar)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To replace an existing notification with a new one you should simply post a notification with the same id, this behavior is mentioned in the documentation of `NotificationManager`'s [notify()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/NotificationManager.html#notify%28int,%20android.app.Notification%29) method. If you want to just remove a notification, call `cancel()` providing the id you used to start it.

Regarding counting the number of notifications your app has sent, I think the best solution would be to just store a counter and increment it once a notification has been sent.

Comment: btw, is there any way I can detect (1) a notification wasn't read yet? (2) the user deleted the notification without reading?