# Disable notifications from other apps

Tags: java, android

i want to disable notifications coming from other apps like Facebook and other apps.

I know it is possible because the [Notifications Off](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.aboutmycode.NotificationsOff) app has this functionality.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android: remove notification from notification bar](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3595232/android-remove-notification-from-notification-bar)

Comment: @SamanGholami That's about how to remove your own notification, not manipulate other apps.

Comment: Read http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/NotificationManager.html please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't, unless you have root or your code runs with system/phone app process id. The app you linked to in your question requires root.

In case you have root and are not afraid to use reflection to access hidden methods, you can examine how [App Settings enables/disables notifications for a package](http://androidxref.com/4.4.2_r2/xref/packages/apps/Settings/src/com/android/settings/applications/InstalledAppDetails.java#setNotificationsEnabled).

Answer (score 5):

Actually, you could achieve this (for API level 18+) with the new [`NotificationListenerService`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/service/notification/NotificationListenerService.html) and the appropriate permissions.

You can use `getActiveNotifications()` to get the list of current notifications in the device, and then `cancelNotification()` to close them individually or `cancelAllNotifications()` to remove them all at once.

So you could be notified (heh) as soon as a notification arrives, then dismiss it if it's from one of these "blocked" applications.