# Hide App Notifications in Android

Tags: android

I'm attempting to write an app that clears certain notifications based on Lollipops new profile features. I've read this: [Android: remove notification from notification bar](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3595232/2844992)
But it doesn't give me the information I need. What I want to know is: theoretically, how would I get another apps notification ID from within mine? So if I wanted to get the ID for G+, how would I code that? Do I even have access without elevated permissions (device admin or root)?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ive done something very similar with one of my apps.
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.t3hh4xx0r.privatenotifications

You need access to the NotificationListener

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/service/notification/NotificationListenerService.html

Comment: Wonderful! Thanks for the straightforward answer.