# Clear push notification automatically after few minutes

Tags: android, parse-platform, push-notification

I have developed parse push notification in my app.

What I want now push notification should clear automatically from notification bar without any click on it after 10 min.Is it possible?

Answer (score 2):

May be this will do the trick please do the required changes

```
Handler handler = new Handler();
    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
              String ns = Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE;
            NotificationManager nMgr = (NotificationManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(ns);
            nMgr.cancel(NOTIF_ID);
        }
    }, 600000);
```

Answer (score 2):

Sure, implement any handler that will wait, and after it remove your notification.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3595232/android-remove-notification-from-notification-bar) is description how to remove notification.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible. Use `Handler`'s [postDelay](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html#postDelayed(java.lang.Runnable,%20long)) to trigger `Notification` [cancel](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/NotificationManager.html#cancel(int)) after 10 min.