# How to count status bar notification meesage in android & how to remove status message when my activity stop?

Tags: android

I want to know how can i count status bar notification meesage in android & how to remove status message when my activity stop ? Any  code snippet would be appericiated

Comment: Have you tried implementing these answers?

Answer (score 1):

Remove the notification on `onDestory` function of Activity.

Answer (score 1):

You need to clear it when you close your application. This means, have an `onDestroy` call.

If your notification is something like:

```
private static final int MY_NOTIFICATION_ID= 1234;
String ns = Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE;
NotificationManager mNotificationManager;
mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(ns);
mNotificationManager.notify(MY_NOTIFICATION_ID, notification);
```

Then you need to implement the following to close it:

```
protected void onDestroy() {
   super.onDestroy();
   mNotificationManager.cancel(MY_NOTIFICATION_ID);
};
```

I grabbed this information from the following posts:

[Remove the notification icon from the status bar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2839727/remove-the-notification-icon-from-the-status-bar)

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html