# Clearing Notifications

Tags: android, notifications

I am making a chat application, I have requirement when the User is logged out of the application, then all the notifications of my application should be removed from the notification bar.

Is it possible??

Thanks

Comment: Just dismiss the notifications when the user logs out.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3595232/android-remove-notification-from-notification-bar

Answer (score 2):

I believe this would do the trick:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/NotificationManager.html#cancelAll()

Or you can cancel them by ID also:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/NotificationManager.html#cancel(int)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, use NotificationManager.cancelAll()

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/NotificationManager.html#cancelAll()

Answer (score 1):

Yes,Take a look here:

[Remove the notification icon from the status bar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2839727/remove-the-notification-icon-from-the-status-bar)

You only need to provide your notification id; to remove only the notifications of your aplication.

When the user logged out or the activity goes to onPause() or onStop() (Depends of your necessity) you use:

```
public void cancel (String tag, int id)
```

**Cancel a previously shown notification. If it's transient, the view will be hidden. If it's persistent, it will be removed from the status bar.**