# Cancel notification on action click with Navigation Components

Tags: android, android-notifications, androidx, android-architecture-navigation

I am using the Android Navigation Component from Androidx to build my pending intents to navigate.

In particular, I am using the pending intents fron Navigation to navigate from my notifications. However, there is no way to cancel the notification when the action has been clicked.

It works correctly if I click in the Notification itself because I am using `setAutoCancel(true)`. However, I can't find any `autoCancel` for the Notification Actions.

This is my code:

```
// Build Pending Intent
val statusPendingIntent = NavDeepLinkBuilder(context)
            .setGraph(R.navigation.navigation)
            .setDestination(R.id.status)
            .createPendingIntent()

// Build Notification Action
val statusAction = NotificationCompat.Action(
        R.drawable.menu_icon_status,
        resources.getString(R.string.menuitem_status),
        statusPendingIntent
)

// Build Notification
val notificationBuilder = NotificationCompat.Builder(context, channelId)
        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.notification_icon)
        .setContentTitle(title)
        .setContentText(message)
        .setContentIntent(someOtherIntent) // This intent cancels the notification as it has "AutoCancel"
        .addAction(statusAction) // This is the notification action. If I click on it, the notification is not cancelled
        .setAutoCancel(true) // AutoCancel itself, closes the notification on tap
```

Has anyone this issue too?

Comment: you mean you can't swipe right to delete the notification?

Comment: I mean, if I click in the action, the notification is not cancelled, and there is no `autoCancel` for actions

Comment: You mean thas?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18335037/remove-notification-when-addaction-called