# setAlarmClock without icon in notification bar

Tags: android, alarmmanager, alarm, android-6.0-marshmallow

To build an exact and reliable Alarm in Android OS 6, aka Marshmallow, I am forced to use [setAlarmClock](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html#setAlarmClock(android.app.AlarmManager.AlarmClockInfo,%20android.app.PendingIntent)) method of AlarmManager. The problem is this method displays an alarm icon in top status bar. Since my app needs an alarm to refresh some data at midnight, everyday, it will display alarm icon forever, which is not pleasant.

Comment: Did u get a ans for this?

Comment: Since you're using Marshmallow, have your tried removing the icon from System UI Tuner? How to enable it here https://www.androidexplained.com/enable-system-ui-tune. Also might be helpful this SO answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/2839911/5466997

Comment: Could you post a copy of how you are using the alarmmanager? It should not behave this way.

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately, this is completely intentional design by the Android developers in order to save battery. This motive becomes clear when you look through the documentation for AlarmManager methods. For example, this quote is taken from the documentation on [`AlarmManager#setExactAndAllowWhileIdle`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager#setExactAndAllowWhileIdle(int,%20long,%20android.app.PendingIntent)):

> These alarms can significantly impact the power use of the device when idle (and thus cause significant battery blame to the app scheduling them), so they should be used with care. **To reduce abuse, there are restrictions on how frequently these alarms will go off** for a particular application. Under normal system operation, it will not dispatch these alarms more than about every minute (at which point every such pending alarm is dispatched); when in low-power idle modes this **duration may be significantly longer, such as 15 minutes**. *[emphasis mine]*

Therefore, Google wants you to signal the user somehow that your app might be draining power by putting the little alarm clock in the status bar if you really really really need to have exact alarms. Quote from the documentation on [`AlarmManager#setAlarmClock`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager#setAlarmClock(android.app.AlarmManager.AlarmClockInfo,%20android.app.PendingIntent)):

> As such, these types of alarms can be extremely expensive on battery use and should only be used for their intended purpose.

Thus, you're left with these two options:

1. Use [`AlarmManager#setExactAndAllowWhileIdle`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager#setExactAndAllowWhileIdle(int,%20long,%20android.app.PendingIntent)) and accept delays up to 15 minutes
2. Use [`AlarmManager#setAlarmClock`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager#setAlarmClock(android.app.AlarmManager.AlarmClockInfo,%20android.app.PendingIntent)) and accept the alarm clock

Comment: Is there any way to hide the time which is shown besides alarm clock icon in notification shadow bar?

Answer (score 2):

You need to use `setExactAndAllowWhileIdle()`. If your app is not ignoring optimizations, you have 10 seconds to achieve your goal. If you need more time, a partial wakelock and/or internet access, you need to add the permission to request to the users to ignore optimizations.

Comment: `setExactAndAllowWhileIdle()` has a problem, I can't have two sequential alarms under 15 mins, as SDK says.

Comment: How can I request to ignore optimizations?

Comment: Yep, it's true but it's only thing you can do.

Comment: All info here: http://developer.android.com/training/monitoring-device-state/doze-standby.html#support_for_other_use_cases

Answer (score -1):

If I understood you correctly you want to use the `AlarmManager` to schedule a task at midnight without displaying the UI clock. You can use [`AlarmManager#set`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html#set(int,%20long,%20android.app.PendingIntent)) this will not display the clock. e.g.

```
  alarm.set(
      AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,
      midnightInMillis,
      PendingIntent.getService(getApplicationContext(), 11, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT)
  );
```

Comment: From the link you posted: `Note: Beginning in API 19, the trigger time passed to this method is treated as inexact: the alarm will not be delivered before this time, but may be deferred and delivered some time later.`, which, according to OP's comment on another answer, is not what OP is looking for.